# What is a good Ruby on Rails and PHP hosting?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, hosting

I'm looking Ruby on Rails and PHP hosting service(shared space or a dedicated server).
I would like to see two options first before buying one of them:

1. PHP and can upgrade to Ruby on Rails later with additional cost
2. Ruby on Rails and PHP

I've looked at [Dreamhost](http://dreamhost.com/), [Bluehost](http://www.bluehost.com/) and [RailsPlayground](http://railsplayground.com/) and all of them seem to have pros and cons. Does anyone have experience with either? Does anyone have a different recommendation?

Comment: Maybe this is meant for http://serverfault.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comments here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162144/what-is-a-good-ruby-on-rails-hosting-service/162213#162213

Dreamhost is a great option. You can run both PHP and Rails and with Private Server option you can move sites that need more resources to a more dedicated platform.

Answer (score 1):

I have dreamhost, while it's cheap and offers a lot of space, it's speed can vary greatly.  They have decent PHP support (file_get_contents() is disabled, among other various things).  Their Rails support is okay, they offer Phusion Passenger(http://www.modrails.com/) to host your Rails apps.

Answer (score 0):

[Slicehost](http://www.slicehost.com) is a pretty good option.  Manage the "slice" yourself (plenty of tutorials and scripts to build your own slice to host PHP and Rails).  Upgrade as needed.  Pretty cheap too.

Comment: Linode is also a good option if you're going to be managing your own VPS.

Answer (score 0):

checout http://heroku.com , they're intended to make rails deployment easy

Comment: The question asked for PHP hosting as well.

Answer (score 0):

[Mediatemple](http://www.mediatemple.net) provides both. I've never had any issues with them

Answer (score 0):

Check out our shared Rails cluster 30 days for free at http://en.railscluster.nl. It runs PHP 5 too!