# Ruby on Rails on Linux hosting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux

I am about learning to program with Ruby on Rails but I'd like to know if web applications built on ROR can be hosted on the regular Linux servers.

Comment: They can be! Check out Linode hosting, they run everything on Linux distros (any you want) and have lots of guides to setting up servers and everything you would need to run RoR out of Linux

Comment: You run Ruby in a container like Passenger or Thin and those can run on any Linux distro you can run Ruby on. Or do you mean in a hosting environment? That's different because shared hosts may not allow you to run Ruby.

Comment: @birryree: Huh? _shared hosts may not allow you to run Ruby_ ? That statement applies to every dev language there is (PHP, Perl, Java, Haskell, Forth, ....) To set the record straight, there are [plenty of places](http://www.google.com/search?q=rails+hosting+shared+server) who will gladly host your ruby/rails app on a shared server.

Comment: As an aside, if you don't want to bother with all the back-end linux stuff, you can go with these two excellent PaaS (platform as a service) providers: [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/) & [EngineYard](http://www.engineyard.com/).

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely. One of the great reference books on Rails, "Agile Web Development with Rails" (written by the guys that created Rails), takes you through a whole demo app that includes server setup, configuration, deployements, everything. They deploy on Linux.

I also ran a site for over a year that was a Rails app, on Linux, and it totally rocked.

I think you'll also find that the broader Rails community prefers Linux. That means when you need help with something, you're much more likely to find someone else who has had your specific problem and is able to help you fix it.

You may also find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339324/selecting-a-rails-host) helpful in choosing - how to select a Rails host (if you don't host it yourself).

Answer (score 2):

Yes they can be and its advised to use Linux Hosting. I hardly if anybody uses windows hosting for Ruby on Rails. As for servers, You can use

- A server called Mongrel ( in a cluster )  Behind Apache or Nginx.
- Unicorn
- Apache with Mod_Rails ( Phusion Passenger )