# Spring Test Transactional annotation not working

Tags: java, spring, jpa, testing, transactions

I have problems getting tests to run with Transaction support.

Here is a way to reproduce:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager;

import javax.transaction.SystemException;

@ContextConfiguration("classpath:applicationContext-hibernate-test.xml")
public class TransactionsTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

  @Transactional
  @Test
  public void testTransactionEnabled() throws SystemException {
    assert TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive(); // works
    assert ! TransactionSynchronizationManager.isCurrentTransactionReadOnly(); // works
    assert TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus() != null; // fails
  }
}
```

Will yield:

- testTransactionEnabled   fails in marked line

This is despite Springs documentation clearly stating that tests annotated with `@Transactional` will cause tests to run within transactions:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testcontext-tx-enabling-transactions

My applicationContext-hibernate-test.xml:

```
<beans...>
  <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2" />
  <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" >...
  </bean>

  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

</beans>
```

Related question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943095

EDIT: the log says:

```
2016-01-08 15:38:31,832 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager:367] - Creating new transaction with name ...
```

So I believe a transaction is indeed created, but it's status cannot be read via `TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus()`, because Spring merely reads the `@Transactional` annotation, but does not instrument the test method, and thus does not bind / undbind the transaction within `TransactionAspectSupport`. If so, I think that might be a bug or at least a desirable feature.

Comment: They will but only if the `TransactionalTestExecutionListener` is present in the `ContextConfigLocation` and that isn't. Hence no transaction and basically your `@Transactional is useless. Also why do you specify your test case as a configuration class, because it isn't... Just load the xml (like the one you commented out). Suggestion remove `@Transactional`, `@Rollback`, `@ImportResource` and `@RunWith` and extend `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests` instead. And change the `@ContextConfiguration` to load the xml instead.

Comment: I tried different variants, also the one you suggest, but no change. I added an edit to the end, which may solve the issue.

Comment: Well first fix your setup as it not really how you should do things. Also I wonder why on earth are you testing things like this?

Comment: Whether the setup is dirty is not relevant to the bug, as long as the setup is valid. And I test this because I have a bug related to code relying on TransactionAspectSupport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I believe TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus() should never be used. Instead:

```
    TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive();
    TransactionSynchronizationManager.isCurrentTransactionReadOnly();
```

should be used (in tests and code), because TransactionAspectSupport really only works on beans annotated with @Transactional, not tests with that annotation, and no other way of using transactions.

So a better suggestion to Spring would be to make the public method TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus() deprecated, as it is bug-prone.